# Create view referencing another view in HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view

I've been trying to create some views in HeidiSQL. The main one needs to read from another view so I need to reference it. If I execute the SQL statement as an independent query (not while creating the view), it executes normally and actually works. However, when I create the view with the exact same query and hit 'SAVE', a pop-up error appears saying that table `ms-configuration`.`devices-by-projects` doesn't exist, while it actually does (it's the other view) and as I have said, the statement executes normally as a query. In the query there's another reference to a view: guests-by-channel. The other ones are real tables.

What could be the error?

```
SELECT `ms-configuration`.`devices-by-projects`.*,
            `guests-by-channel`.`name` AS `name`,
            `guests-by-channel`.`surname` AS `surname` 
from ((`ms-configuration`.`devices-by-projects` 
    left join `ms-guests`.`tablet_sessions` on((`ms-configuration`.`devices-by-projects`.`uuid` = `ms-guests`.`tablet_sessions`.`tablet_id`))) 
    left join `ms-guests`.`guests-by-channel` on(((`ms-guests`.`tablet_sessions`.`room` = `guests-by-channel`.`room`) 
                                                                                and (`ms-guests`.`tablet_sessions`.`pin` = `guests-by-channel`.`pin`) 
                                                                                and (`ms-guests`.`tablet_sessions`.`PID` = `guests-by-channel`.`PID`) 
                                                                                and (`ms-guests`.`tablet_sessions`.`channel` = `guests-by-channel`.`channel_id`) 
                                                                                and (`guests-by-channel`.`deleted` <> 1) 
                                                                                and (`guests-by-channel`.`check_out` >= cast(now() as date)) 
                                                                                and (`ms-guests`.`tablet_sessions`.`channel` = `guests-by-channel`.`channel_id`))))
```

Comment: You appear to be acquiring from number of different databases  - which DB are you USEing when you do this?

Comment: You could improve this query by removing all the unnecessary brackets and the judicious use of aliases. Also why cause pain by using identifiers which would be illegal if not backticked.

Comment: I'm using HeidiSQL, and the brackets were actually added by it automatically. Also, what do you mean with aliases and identifiers?

Comment: Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL) and respond to my first comment.

Comment: Alright, I'll read it, thanks. And about the database, I'm creating the view in 'ms-configuration'